# Error when writing a file with "len(lst)" when it is empty

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function but I have the following problem:

```
File "/home/python/functions.py", line 298, in function
    fileout.write("%i \n\n")%(len(lst_one))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

`#lst_one` is correctly defined in the script. I think it is because `lst_one` is still empty and so `%i` doesn't work(`%s` doesn't work also).

Is there some way to avoid the TypeError?

Comment: @DeepSpace better yet, use `.format` method!

Comment: @DeepSpace What is .format? Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `lst_one` being empty (as long as by "empty" you mean an emoty list or string). You have a misplaced ')'.
 `fileout.write("%i \n\n") % (len(lst_one))` should be 
`fileout.write("%i \n\n" % (len(lst_one)))`.

Or use a more convenient method for string formatting:
`fileout.write("{} \n\n".format(len(lst_one)))` as suggested in the comments by 
@ juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: Great. Now i will try it. What means { }?

Comment: @santimirandarp Please see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format